# Get unlock passcode of a jailbroken iPad/iPhone using TransLock Bruteforce Tool

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, password, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPad 3 that I haven't touched in a couple of years, and forgot the 4-digit passcode. The MacBook Pro that I used to backup and sync the iPad recently crashed. So, I cannot connect and restore the iPad without losing my precious data; particularly a book's manuscript that I was partially writing in Notes.

After 9 failed attempts, I am down to my last attempt before the iPad is locked. I've tried numerous applications to try and backup the iPad in DFU/Restore mode to no avail.

Then I came across: Majd Alfhaily's post http://blog.alfhaily.me/2015/03/bruteforce/ where he was able to accomplish the exact task that I am trying to do using his TransLock Brutefore tool. I tried to replicate his work, but my programming skills are limited. I got as far as downloading his libTransLock file on my GitHub...(https://github.com/freemanrepo/libTransLock).

Does anyone know how to compile or execute his work? Has anyone else been successful at bypassing the passcode on a jailbroken iPad/ iPhone using TransLock or another tool? Any comments or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never tried it. Ultimately erasing the iPad is the standard solution. If you have a backup you can restore the backup.

Comment: Please tell us that you have the manuscript backed up and the copy on the iPad is not the unique one...

Comment: If your iPad is jailbroken and you have access to the file system to be able to install packages and inject code via MobileSubstrate - why not just copy the Notes file with your manuscript to a PC/Mac?

Comment: The previous backup is on the MBP's SSD HD that recently crashed.  I also used the same MBP to jailbreak the iPad, so I no longer have access to the file system on the iPad. The section of the manuscript regarding medical translations were written solely within Notes. Sadly, my only copy is on the iPad. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

libTransLock is a tweak you'll need to compile with Theos and install on the device.

1. Install [Theos](https://github.com/theos/theos/wiki/Installation).
2. Clone [libTransLock](https://github.com/freemanrepo/libTransLock) to a folder on your computer.
3. Connect your jailbroken device with USB.
4. Run `make package install` in the cloned folder.
5. SSH into your jailbroken device.
6. Run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` on your device to watch the syslog. You should see lines like

   ```
   Testing : 0000
   Testing : 0001
   ⋮
   Password is : 1234
   ```

   That's the password!
7. Once you're back in, uninstall the tweak in Cydia.